# MS Access 365 ChartControl.OnUpdated(Code???)

Tags: charts, subform

What are valid values for Code in the MS Access 365 ChartControl.OnUpdated(Code) event and what are their functions?  I am unable to find a help page on this topic.

I ask because I have a chart control subform that updates fine when I select a parent form record that populates the subform chart control with data.  However, when I select a new record in the parent form, there is no data for the subform chart control and the ole server crashes.  I'm hoping there is a value for Code that will allow me to stop the chart control from refreshing on empty data.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give me.

Comment: Every time the chart is updated, this event is fired. You can write an event handler to control what happens on update. Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Comment: Mitko, thank you.  That is my intention.  I am working in VBA and am looking for guidance on the "Code" parameter passed to this event.

Comment: I have not been clear in my description. "Code" is an integer parameter passed in the event handler. It does not have the same meaning as in "programming code".